# javascript is called automatically

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a javascript function that keeps being processed automatically everytime I reload my jsp.. Although I was supposed to call it on button click.. why is that?

maybe I have errors on syntax, can you help?
here's the code:

```
<form class="form-grp clearfix mse_pre_init" id="widgetu599" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ><!-- none box -->
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u604-4"><!-- content -->
  <p>Submitting Form...</p>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u606-4"><!-- content -->
  <p>The server encountered an error.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u605-4"><!-- content -->
  <p>Form received.</p>
 </div>
 <input class="submit-btn NoWrap grpelem" id="u607-17" type="submit" value="" tabindex="3" onClick = "printform()"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
<script>


function printform(){

    admit();

}

function admit(){
       <%
        String assessment_id = "";
        String section = "";
        String s_id = (String)session.getAttribute("id");
        String payment1;

        PreparedStatement pst, pst1;
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;

    try{

        String sql2="select * from assessment_tbl order by assessment_id + 1";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system", "root","");
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.last()){

            String ass = rs.getString("assessment_id");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(ass);
            int b = a + 1;
            String asss = Integer.toString(b);
            assessment_id = asss;

        }
        else{

            assessment_id = "1";

        }


    {%>
    var a = document.getElementById("payment");
    var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

    if(b === "Full Payment"){
        if(document.getElementById("id1").checked || document.getElementById("id2").checked || document.getElementById("id3").checked){

            alert('Select Insallment First!');

        }
        else{
        <%payment1="1";
        String sqlhaha= "Insert into assessment_tbl values ('"+assessment_id+"', '"+con_num+"', '"+section+"', '"+s_id+"', '"+payment1+"', '"+year1+"')";
        pst1=con.prepareStatement(sqlhaha);
        pst1.executeUpdate();

        %>



    }
    }
    else{

        if(document.getElementById("id1").checked){




        }
        else if(document.getElementById("id2").checked){



        }
        else if(document.getElementById("id3").checked){



        }
        else{
            alert('Select Semestral/Quarterly/Monthly');
        }

    }
    <%}





    }
    catch(Exception e){



    }

%> 


}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: which function are you refering to

Comment: it might be helpful to see the code from the client side (aka "View Source") - it might be clearer where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got wrong what happens with jsp before your page is sent to browser. Remember that every java code `<% java code %>` is performed before sending the page to client side. Java code(server code) won't be performed after javascript onclick action is fired (client side function `admit()`).

Java code `<% %>` is performed when page is being rendered. So every little bit of this java code will happen every time you reload page.

If you need to communicate from client side (browser) to server using JavaScript (without client relaoding page), you need to use asynchronous technology AJAX (Async. JavaScript And Xml). Dont be confused from title you can use for example json for data exchange.

Comment: what solutions could you suggest sir?

Comment: I eddited answer and added suggestion. You need to use **AJAX**, you will send data to specified server endpoint (for example **REST** api) and server will process your request and return result data. You can then show this result data to user using javascript. There is no easy way for performing server code as you would like to :-(.

Comment: I made a servlet where I put the codes,, then I called them.. but the form redirects to the page... how can I prevent it from redirecting?

Comment: If you wnat to handle send form only with javascript and preventing sending the form (in your case to same page) you have to return false from js function. [From with JavaScript](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59) you can hide information for example here